# Empty room list on region change

Tags: unity, photon

I am using PUN2 for my game and I am using the `OnRoomListUpdate()` function to sync my UI with the rooms that are available to players when they are in the lobby. The room lists come back from Photon just fine until I switch regions. If I switch regions and rejoin the lobby, I get the `OnRoomListUpdate()` event but no rooms are handed back for that region when I know I have rooms open. Below is the code I have for switching regions:

```
public void ConnectToRegion(string region)
{
    PhotonNetwork.Disconnect();
    PhotonNetwork.PhotonServerSettings.AppSettings.FixedRegion = region;

    if (!PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings())
    {
        Debug.LogError("Unable to connect.");
    }
    else
    {
        PhotonNetwork.JoinLobby();
        currentRegionText.text = $"Current region: {region}";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested myself, but what's sticking out to me is that you're attempting to join lobby right away after calling ConnectUsingSettings, which has some asynchronous work to do.  In my project I call JoinLobby after receiving the OnConnectedToMaster callback.  So perhaps you're just trying to join the lobby too soon?

EDIT: The disconnect is asynchronous as well.  I just needed to put something together myself so here is something you can do (I used the connection callbacks in mine but coroutines should work too, as below).  I also used "ConnectToRegion" so that I don't mess with server settings.  This works for me, I'm seeing rooms from the selected region.

```
   public void SwitchToRegion(string region)
   {
      StartCoroutine(SwitchToRegionCoroutine(region));
   }

   IEnumerator SwitchToRegionCoroutine(string region)
   {
      PhotonNetwork.Disconnect();
      yield return new WaitWhile(() => { return PhotonNetwork.IsConnected; });
      PhotonNetwork.ConnectToRegion(region);
      yield return new WaitUntil(() => { return PhotonNetwork.IsConnected; });
      PhotonNetwork.JoinLobby();
   }
```